# How to remove the themed CSS file in an aspx page in a Web Application

Tags: css, asp.net, themes, export-to-word, app-themes

I am using a **css** file in **App_Theme** in a webform WebApplication using ASP.net 4.6
In one of the page I dont want the Themed CSS file. The reason is that I want to export the content of the page to a word document. If I remove

```
runat="server"
```

from **head** tag it gives error. 
Pls let me know if any one has a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the below tags in "Page" directive.
EnableTheming="false" Theme="" StylesheetTheme=""